# Tableview header view not cleared when reloading to particular section

Tags: ios

[image]I have a table view with sections headers which contain label and button.
on button click, add the particular section in the array and pass it to numberofRows function to expand and remove particular section index from the array when collapsed to perform expand/collapsed feature. I am loading Separate XIB to each section row when expanding. But when I scroll to the particular section using 'scrollToRowAtIndexPath' then other section headers not move sometimes accordingly. in below image I have opened the clock section by clicking on header button but previous Twitter section header not cleared when I scroll fast.The Twitter section should be shown below clock section's Row.

Comment: Try to share some code.

Comment: and to add one gif to show your issue.

Comment: hey please find my edited question.